# SSRS/SQL Report Conundrum - If X and Y, Mark intersecting cell Z

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have never seen this question posed... I need to create a report where the X axis is a condition and the Y axis is an item. If an Item meets a condition, I need an "X" in the intersecting cell.

Example :

```
         Frog      Sky      Lollipop

Red        X                   X
Blue       X        X          X
Green      X
```

With that example, more specifically I need to show, in that format, Security groups across the top and functions down the side. The "X" would indicate which group would have which functions.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: it seems you need to use Pivot function.

Comment: please post code to create sample tables, sample rows and show the expected output.

Comment: You would need to provide some examples of how your data is stored. It looks easy enough to do with a matrix in SSRS. But again until you give us some details on the table structures and data all we see is Red, blue and green frogs, blue sky and red and blue lollipop.. :)